# SaaS renewable subscriptions: Apple and revenue share with other B2B partners

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, saas, subscriptions

This question is regarding a SaaS business with mobile and web apps with renewable subscriptions.

We are considering for the mobile apps to go for Apple revenue share (IAP renewable subscriptions), so we can also provide a sign-up screen for direct users that find us in that channel.

At the same time we have B2B partners who do their own billing for our SaaS (revenue share model) and the users download the IOS app for free.

Technically, the registrations from these channels are separate and can be handled separately on our servers and so are the payments.

However we are not 100% sure if Apple can and will claim revenue share for the users from partners that have downloaded the app, yet are not paying via IAP but via the partner?

Has any developer debated this with the Apple team before?

Answer (score 1):

From my experience there is no debate with Apple.

From Apple guidelines: https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#content-based-reader-apps

- 3.1.3 “Reader” Apps: Apps may allow a user to access previously purchased content or content subscriptions (specifically: magazines, newspapers, books, audio, music, video, access to professional databases, VoIP, cloud storage, and approved services such as educational apps that manage student grades and schedules), as well as consumable items in multi-platform games, provided that you agree not to directly or indirectly target iOS users to use a purchasing method other than in-app purchase, and your general communications about other purchasing methods are not designed to discourage use of in-app purchase.
- 3.1.4 Content Codes: Apps may not use their own mechanisms to unlock content or functionality, such as license keys, augmented reality markers, QR codes, etc. In limited circumstances, such as when features are dependent upon specific hardware to function, the app may unlock that functionality without using in-app purchase (e.g. an astronomy app that adds features when synced with a telescope). App features that work in combination with an approved physical product (such as a toy) on an optional basis may unlock functionality without using in-app purchase, provided that an in-app purchase option is available as well. You may not, however, require users to purchase unrelated products or engage in advertising or marketing activities to unlock app functionality.

You can allow access to the app for free and unlock "premium" functionalities through your site, however you can't do any reference to the user to become premium inside the app if you're not offering IAP.

This is the Spotify strategy. You cannot subscribe for premium inside the app, and the app doesn't do any reference to the user to become premium. However, you can access the site and buy a subscription that is valid also inside the app.

In your case, you are offering both, from my understanding:

> Apps may allow a user to access previously purchased content

Allow you to follow your strategy to have web subscription then access the app.

Comment: Thank you, GIJOW, for your swift answer! We are thinking along the same lines - though we do not sell third party content but we do offer a free account as the starting point. I will check the registration steps for Spotify in iOS again (have had the app for a while) though I read in the news that they got blocked by Apple a couple of times recently. I checked Slack as well - I can register from the iOS app (in a bit of a roundabout process) but there are no in app purchases listed. I voted up your answer but I am too new for them to be shown.

Comment: @A.Mayfair I do the same in one of our app, we have a free version, and a premium one. User can buy using IAP or through web. Or can buy in Android and use in iOS, cross platform I mean. I think you'll have no problems

Comment: Did Apple allow you to have a registration screen for your app? or just a login screen?

Comment: Yes. I do have sign up process inside the app.

Comment: Thank you, again, very much for taking time to answer! Have a great day!